# What is the best way to detect an ARM-CPU with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, arm, arm64

What is the most reliable way to detect an ARM processor architecture using Delphi (running on Windows 11 ARM)?

Comment: Well, since ARM vs x86 vs x64 are different architectures you have to compile for individually, I would think using `{$IFDEF}` would work, ie `{$IFDEF CPUARM}`. See [Predefined Conditionals](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)#Predefined_Conditionals)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Windows on Arm has an x86 emulation layer (on Windows 11 also x64) so binaries build for x86 can run on Arm. So I think OP is asking runtime detection not compile time?

Answer (score 3):

Remy's suggestion above is fine, but if you want to detect if an x86/x64 program is running on an ARM Windows, I think you can do it this way (untested, as I don't have access to an ARM Windows):

```
TYPE
  TImageFileMachine     = USHORT;
  TIsWow64Process2      = FUNCTION(Handle : THandle ; VAR ProcessMachine,NativeMachine : TImageFileMachine) : LongBool; stdcall;

CONST
  IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM64 = $AA64;

FUNCTION IsARM : BOOLEAN;
  VAR
    F   : TIsWow64Process2;
    P,N : TImageFileMachine;

  BEGIN
    @F:=GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'),'IsWow64Process2');
    IF NOT Assigned(F) THEN
      Result:=FALSE
    ELSE IF NOT F(GetCurrentProcess,P,N) THEN
      Result:=FALSE
    ELSE
      Result:=(N=IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM64)
  END;
```

Comment: This example in c# might also be helpful: https://github.com/rweijnen/SharpWow64ApiSet (not placing that as an answer because it does essentially the same and is not in Delphi)

Comment: I wonder if this really works? According to the `GetNativeSystemInfo()` documentation: "*If the function is called from an x86 or x64 application running on a 64-bit system that does not have an Intel64 or x64 processor (**such as ARM64**), **it will return information as if the system is x86** only if x86 emulation is supported (or x64 if x64 emulation is also supported).*" Makes me wonder if `IsWow64Process2()` works similarly. Will it actually report `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM64` in an x86 app on ARM64, or will it report something more like `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The `pNativeMachine` parameter of `IsWow64Process2` On success, returns a pointer to a possible` IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_*` value identifying the native architecture of host system

Comment: @Remko Yes, I can read the documentation, thank you. You clearly missed my point. `GetNativeSystemInfo()` is also supposed to identify the native architecture when called by an x86 app under WOW64, but it is documented as reporting *emulated* x86 info when called by an x86 app on ARM64. So I question whether `IsWow64Process2()` reports the architecture as *actual* ARM64, or *emulated* x86, when called by an x86 app on ARM64. Like HeartWare, I don't have an ARM64 system to test with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've tested it (with the c# code on my GH) but it's a while ago. I remember it does work correctly but I'll retest and confirm...

Comment: @RemyLebeau it works per docs for me, returns `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM64` as Native Machine. I've added a screenshot to the repo: https://github.com/rweijnen/SharpWow64ApiSet/blob/main/screenshot.png

Comment: Confirmed on Win11 ARM running under Parallels on a MAC.

Comment: According to the following link, the only way to determine if a process is running in an x86 emulation environment is by using IsWow64Process2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/apps-on-arm-x86-emulation

Comment: @JHJang: And that's the one I using, so... ?